# Will Dragonfly flyby Jupiter en route to Saturn?

Tags: gravity-assist, jupiter, flyby

The table on the "[Exploration of Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploration_of_Jupiter)" Wikipedia page suggests [Dragonfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonfly_(spacecraft)) will be the first mission to the outer planets that will not use a gravity assist from Jupiter. Is there a source confirming this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327110307_Preliminary_Interplanetary_Mission_Design_and_Navigation_for_the_Dragonfly_New_Frontiers_Mission_Concept) is a paper which among other things includes the results of a trajectory search. They say

> Gravity assists of Earth, Venus, and Mars were included with a patched conics assumption. Jupiter was immediately discarded as it is out of phase during the desired time period.

The trajectories proposed in that paper involve multiple Earth and Venus flybys. I guess if the mission was delayed a few years then Jupiter might come back into play.

Comment: I'd guesstimate a landing in 2042 if a Jupiter flyby is included. Relative positions of Jupiter and Saturn repeat every 21 years.